Is it possible to know if an internal module has already been required
In a Node.js application one can use require.cache to check if a module that exists on disk has been required. However this list doesn't contain internal modules such as http.
Is it possible to check if an internal module has been required by the application?
One could wrap the require() function early in the process but I'm hoping for a solution that works later in the process lifecycle.

Why would you need to know this at all? What problem are you trying to solve that you think this would be a (partial) solution to? (Also, note that require.cache doesn't exist in ESM context)

I work on a product that monkey patches globals and npm libraries and would like to proactively warm users when they load our library too late. For example if an http server is already listening then the product won't work properly.

Given the (slower than I'd like, but hey) move towards ESM, you may want to consider doing an "instance patching" as well. That way, rather than relying on magic, users can do things like doTheThing(myServer), where doTheThing wraps the passed object in a Proxy that can do "whatever you need" (e.g. like https://github.com/Pomax/js-call-tracer - I originally considered monkey patching, but letting users be explicit about what they need won out)
